# Как вызвать функцию при нажатии кнопки домой (Xcode, разработка iOS приложений)

Tags: ios, xcode, функции

Мне нужна функция, которая будет вызываться при нажатии кнопки домой, или просто при закрытии приложения

Comment: По возможности, опубликуйте найденное решение в [ответе к вашему вопросу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Уверен, оно в будущем поможет многим вашим коллегам.

Answer (score 1):

При нажатии кнопки домой приложение сворачивается, соответственно срабатывает метод `applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application` в AppDelegate. Вам нужно лишь имплементировать этот метод в AppDelegate.m(.swift)

Comment: не понятно, можно по-подробнее, как запихнуть функцию из appdelegate в viewcontroller?

Comment: Я уже сам разобрался, надо написать этот код в **AppDelegate**
 `func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
            print("bye")
        
         NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("out", object: self)
}`  
А это засунуть в нужный **ViewController** 

`override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(home), name: "out", object: nil)
}`
У меня все работает прекрасно. А еще у меня не хочет переходить на новую строку, ни 2 пробела, ни <br/> не помогают